# tuple file in standard c++ library folder got corrupt. How to modify?

Tags: c++, c++11

Tuple file in c++ library folder got corrupted somehow. My compiler is giving input output error due to tuple source file. I want to modify that file but i can neither delete that file nor i can copy a new file. I am using ubuntu 16.04. How to replace tuple file?

Comment: You should have your filesystem checked and repaired. Use `fsck`.

Comment: If you can't delete it, it's because a process is using it. Kill those processes and delete file (with -f flag if needed). Then you download the file and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You (or an administrator) needs to restore a good copy of the file from somewhere.  You will probably have to be logged in as `root` to do this - either by logging in, or using `su`, or by using `sudo`.

If you don't know what those commands do, you will need an administrator - you can *really* bork your machine with them.

Comment: I have already downloaded a copy of tuple file from internet. But problem is i can neither delete original file nor can i replace it with my new downloaded file. What should i do?

Comment: A copy "from the internet" is unlikely to ever work with the rest of your standard library and toolchain.

Comment: @Quentin - it depends.  If it's a copy of the distribution of libstc++ the OP is using, then it will be fine.

Comment: @AatifJamshaidMalik Have you tried deleting the file *as root*?  If you don't know how to do that, you will need to get an administrator to do it for you.